# How to insert a JavaScript variable into Flask url_for() function?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have following code in my Flask template:

```
<div id="cell1"></div>
<script>
var id="0014";
cell1.innerHTML = '<a href={{url_for('static',filename='+id+'".txt")}}">'+id+'</a>';
</script>
```

I want the link to render to:

```
http://my_address/static/0014.txt
```

But I got this:

```
http://my_address/static/+id+.txt
```

How to make the js variable `id` in Flask `url_for()` function work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could it be that you are mixing server side and client side code? What's this {{url_for(...)}} stuff, some sort of template engine method? If so, you need to work on the result of the function call.

Comment: I think you've a quotes issue, try to use `cell1.innerHTML = '<a href={{url_for("static", filename="'+id+'.txt")}}">'+id+'</a>';`

Comment: Quotes escape `'<a href={{url_for("static",filename="'+id+'.txt")}}">'+id+'</a>'`

Comment: Thanks Quagaar and Zakaria Achrki for yours suggestions. Grey Li gave me the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<a href={{ url_for('static', filename='') }}' + id + '.txt>' + id + '</a>';
```

`url_for()` will generate an URL like this: `.../static/<filename>`. If you use `url_for('static', filename='')`, it generate an URL like: `.../static/`, so you can just add text after it (i.e. `+ id + '.txt>'`) .

Comment: Dear, Thank you very much!   It Works!

Comment: sorry, for the moment I not have sufficient reputation for vote, but when I have it will do it.